# How to create angular 5 project in angular cli 6.0.1

Tags: angular6

My **angular cli version is 6.0.1** and **node** version is **8.11.1**.

[image: image of version]

How to create or add a new project of angular 5.

If I use *ng new [project_name]* then the project is downloading that is of *angular 6*.

Comment: Following the answer from @ashish.gd It is also possible to install different version of Angular in the same machine:

1. Create a new folder and instantiate a node project with `npm init`.
2. Install the Angular-CLI that related to the version that you need.
3. Remove `package.json` file.
4. Create/Import an Angular project that will have the version related to the CLI.

Further reading and explanation here: https://medium.com/@ferie/how-to-install-a-specific-angular-version-16d4766341f3

Answer (score 22):

I stumbled upon this scenario too.
Here is my solution to it.

Unfortunately we are at the CLI's mercy, as the best way to create a new Angular project scaffolding.
Considering `ng new {app_name}` does not support a version flag.
Our aim would be to get the right CLI version installed.

The following steps helped me workaround this:

1. Create a new folder:  `mkdir ng-5-cli && cd ng-5-cli`
2. Initialise NPM `npm init`
3. Install older Angular CLI: `npm i @angular/cli@1.7.4 --save-dev`
4. For some reason now the ng compiler assumes this is a angular project directory and does not allow running `ng new` here.
5. Step out of the current directory: `cd ..`
6. Use the absolute path to Angular cli in the directory from step #1.

For example `/ng-5-cli/node_modules/.bin/ng new some-ng5-app`

This should create a new application with Angular version 5.x .

*You can always install other cli versions and create custom softlinks for them to use in future.*

Answer (score 5):

I have found a good explanation and the steps how to do -

https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-5-or-angular-6-yes-please-d71b08b5e59b

1) Install Angular 6 CLI globally:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@6
```

2) Create a folder called ng5 to house all of your new Angular 5 applications:

```
md ng5
cd ng5
```

3) In your ng5 folder create a new local npm application by using:

```
npm init -y
```

4) Install Angular 5 CLI locally using:

```
npm install @angular/cli@1
```

5) Now you MUST delete the local package.json file.
If you don’t, Angular CLI will complain when you try use ng new. This is because it will think you are trying to create a new application inside an existing Angular CLI application.

6) Create your new Angular 5 application:

```
ng new my-ng5-app
```