# I update my Angular CLI to 6.0.7 and now i want to create a project using Angular 4/5. How to do that?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-cli, angular6, angular-cli-v6

- I have my angular cli update to 6.0.7.
- I want to create a new Angular 4/5 project using ng new command.

Please help me as I use ng new command Angular 6 project is being created

Answer (score 2):

Downgrade your `node` and `angular-cli` version

Than you are able to create project in version 5

> PS: You can use `NVM` which will allow you to handle multiple node/angular-cli versions

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need to downgrade `node` version.

Refer: [How to create angular 5 project in angular cli 6.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305342/how-to-create-angular-5-project-in-angular-cli-6-0-1/50467119#50467119)

The same process is applicable for all angular versions until the cli allows specifying the version with `ng new`